# How to step to the next line in Matlab debugger?

Tags: matlab, debugging

I dropped a breakpoint in MATLAB and am in debug mode. I'd like to evaluate the current line and move on to the next line without exiting debug mode or adding additional breakpoints. In other debuggers, I've used the `next` command, but this doesn't seem to work in MATLAB. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: @thewaywewalk I needed the command window version, but most people seem to need the GUI instruction. Can you put both in your answer?

Comment: well that would be Luis Mendo's answer then, you can just accept his answer, I don't have a problem with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it from the command window, use [`dbstep`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstep.html):

> `dbstep` executes the next executable line of the current file during debugging, skipping any breakpoints set in functions called by the current line.

See the linked documentation for optional parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the **`Step`**-Button (F10):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use F9 button to execute only specific lines of code. For example you need to execute first 5 rows, then check workspace, then execute next 3 rows. To do that just select 5 rows, press F9, then check workspace for changes then select next 3 rows and press F9 and so on.